# WPF GlyphRuns and context-dependent characters

Tags: wpf, text, glyph

I am trying to render Arabic text in WPF at Glyph level, on a character-by-character basis. Rendering Latin text was easy, each character simply translates to a Unicode codepoint and I used GlyphTypeface's CharacterToGlyphMap dictionary to retrieve a GlyphRun for each character.

With Arabic (and other languages) it seems that things are a lot more complicated: characters use different glyphs depending on the characters that surround them and on their position in a word. I suppose these contextual character forms all have their own Unicode codepoints too.

My questions are:
- How would I get these context-dependendent codepoints? A TextBlock displays Arabic text correctly (I suppose), how does it know which glyphs to use?
- Would that character-after-character approach even work for Arabic or is there more that I should know?

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this issue ?